# To dance oneself

Tags: complements, reflexives, intransitive-verbs

LCD Soundsystem sings about *Danc(ing) Yrself clean*, Sesame Street's muppets sing about *Danc(ing) myself to sleep*, Alice Cooper about *Danc(ing) yourself to death* and on its website the British Royal academy of dance suggests you *dance yourself happy*.

I can find almost no information about this structure: *to dance oneself + adj. / to dance oneself to + n.* It looks quite unusual to me (as a non-native English speaker) as the verb *to dance* is used:

- in a reflexive form although it is not even transitive to begin with;
- with a prepositional or adjectival complement that apparently indicates an outcome state.

What is the origin for this? Is it considered informal or even incorrect? I have also found occurrences with other verbs like *to sing oneself to sleep*. Under which circumstances can this structure be generalized ? Can I *run myself tired/to tiredness*? or *toil myself satisfied/to satisfaction*?

Comment: You can run yourself ragged and work yourself silly.

Comment: [Verb] yourself [adjective] is a standard, if fairly informal, usage for [verb] until you are [adjective].

Comment: You can dance yourself happy, drive me crazy, paint the barn red... Object complements.

Comment: Though only for active verbs with human subjects. I suspect (though I haven't looked closely) that the reflexive is a [B-Raised subject](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf).

Comment: You *run yourself to exhaustion*, not *to tiredness*. These expressions are kind of like idioms, in that they don't always work if you substitute synonyms.

Comment: Don't some people, e.g. dervishes, dance themselves into a trance, or frenzy, or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=drank+himself+silly%2Cran+himself+ragged%2Cworked+himself+to+death%2Ccried+herself+to+sleep%2Cdanced+himself+to+sleep&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) show that various [V] [P ref] [Adj]/[to N] (and including other prepositional heads) strings have been used for quite some time. But they also show that these unusual resultative constructions are ... unusual. One needs to check each for idiomaticity before using it without wishing to sound quirky or even slangy.

[image]

And I think you'll agree that Google ngrams isn't an accurate enough tool to distinguish 'acceptable' from quirky examples; the near-flatlines shown (and the flatline for 'danced himself to sleep') should probably be disregarded.

A check using a raw Google search may even be a more accurate diagnostic, but asking seasoned Anglophones (and intelwise younger Anglophones) may be the better way to decide on acceptability.

The resultative construction is not limited to reflexive pronouns:

- *They ran their mother / her ragged.*
- *Bob drank John under the table.*

Answer (score 1):

> in a reflexive form although it is not even transitive to begin with;

This statement is incorrect. "Dance" is indeed beng used as a transitive verb in these sentences.

> to dance oneself to + n

This is not the correct idiom. The preposition "to" is part of a collocation with "sleep". As you noticed, you can sing yourself to sleep. You can also go to sleep, put a baby to sleep, etc.

Except for semantics (how would dancing get you clean?), I don't see anything unusual about any of the sentences.

Comment: _> Dance" is indeed beng used as a transitive verb in these sentences._
My point was that precisely these cases are unlike the more familiar use of dance which is typically intransitive (expect in the cases where an object is used to indicate a type of dance but AFAIK you never dance "somebody else").
_> I don't see anything unusual about any of the sentences._
Including my propositions? The second part of my question was "Can this structure be freely generalized to any verb/adjective combination?"

Comment: You ***can*** dance somebody else. In Leonard Cohen's song, he asks his partner to *dance me to the end of love.* In lots of fairy tales, they *dance people to death.*  You can *dance your baby to sleep.* And Google finds occasional (quite rare) similar constructions. *Dance yourself clean* isn't any more unusual than these transitive constructions.

Comment: @PeterShor For me *rocking your baby* without any further arguments is unremarkable, but *singing your baby* and *dancing your baby* sound funny unless they have something to follow. You can sing songs and dance tangos, but singing a baby or dancing them is just weird. :)

Comment: @Burakumin *The second part of my question was "Can this structure be freely generalized to any verb/adjective combination?"* No, because in most instances people wouldn't recognize it as an extension of "to sleep". You can't "run yourself to tiredness" (at least in common speech). You would need some other reason for "to".

Comment: @Burakumin *Including my propositions?* Cooper's "to death" might be understood as an extension of "to sleep" (which is fine), and we use expressions such as "to the death" and "till death do us part", so his phrase seems pretty understandable. I don't see any other prepositions in the example phrases.